# How to make horizontal list elements not to stack on each other in react?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

Basically I made a horizontal list using html and css. Everything was working fine until I copied the same code to my react app. In react everything was working but it seems like some style in the stylesheet is making list's elements to stack on each other. That's the code in html with stylesheet:

```css
.os{
    width:800px;
    height: 20px;
    list-style: none;
    text-align: justify;
    margin: 80px auto;
    background-color: black;
}
.os:after {
    display: inline-block;
    content: "";
    width: 100%;
}
.os li{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background: blueviolet;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 1.2;
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 50%;
    
}
.os li:before{
    display: inline-block;
    content: attr(data-year);
    font-size: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}
.os li:nth-child(odd):before{
    top:-40px;
}
.os li:nth-child(even):before{
    bottom:-40px;
}
.os li:after{
    display: inline-block;
    content: attr(data-text);
    font-size: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}
.os li:nth-child(odd):after{
    top:40px;
}
.os li:nth-child(even):after{
    bottom:40px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>react</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul class="os">
            <li data-year="2016" data-text="lorem"></li>
            <li data-year="2017" data-text="ipsum"></li>
            <li data-year="2018" data-text="dolor"></li>     
            <li data-year="2018" data-text="dolor"></li>   
        </ul>      
   </body>
</html>
```

React code looks like this:

```
render(){
   
         return(
            <ul className="os">
                 {/*{json.map((row,index)=>{
                     var tytul = row.tytul
                     var data = row.data
                     return  <li key={row.id} data-year={data} data-text={tytul}></li>
                    
                 })}*/}     
                <li data-year="2016" data-text="lorem"></li>
                <li data-year="2017" data-text="ipsum"></li>
                <li data-year="2018" data-text="dolor"></li>     
                <li data-year="2018" data-text="dolor"></li>    
            </ul>
                )
             }
```

But it looks like this [img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JlCj4.png).
To both html and react app I linked the same stylesheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess your `text-align: justify;` in class `.os` not good idea to use it.  Try this.

```
.os {
  width:800px;
  height: 20px;
  list-style: none;
  /* text-align: justify; */ /* Remove this line */
  margin: 80px auto;
  background-color: black;
  display: grid; /* New line */
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, 200px); /* New line */
}
```